# Store Exception Class Name for StandardError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling

I have defined a couple of custom exception classes that inherit from StandardError like so:

```
class InvalidPage < StandardError;end
```

If this exception is being raised I want to rescue it and store it to my DB for reference. So far I save its message and backtrace, but I can't seem to save its Name (InvalidPage) as well. I have tried:

```
InvalidPage.class
InvalidPage.class.name
InvalidPage.name
```

but none of the above works for me.

How can I access and save the Exception Name together with the message and backtrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class InvalidPage < StandardError; end

begin
  raise InvalidPage

rescue InvalidPage => error      
  p error.class.to_s
  p error.backtrace

end

# Output
# "InvalidPage"
# ["file.rb:4:in `<main>'"]
```